Doubts on von Neumann's infinite tensor product of Hilbert spaces
I am reading the original paper by von Neumann on infinite tensor product of Hilbert spaces, and there are few things that are not fully clear to me.
Given $K = \otimes_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{H}_i, p_i)$, where $p_i$ is a vector in the Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}_i$, a vector $\otimes_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \psi_i$ is in $K$ if and only if the weak equivalence relation is satisfied: $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} | <\psi_i|p_i> -1  | < + \infty.$ My doubts:

What is an ONB of K?
If we have $\phi = \sum_{k \in I} c_k \psi^k$, where $I \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, $\psi^k = \otimes_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \psi_{i}^{k}$ and each $\psi^k \in K$, and finally $\sum_{k \in I} |c_k|^2 = 1$, how can I check if $\phi \in K$?
Is the von Neumann definition of infinite tensor product of Hilbert spaces the only way to define it? Any reference is welcome.


Linear combinations of finite tensors are dense (by finite tensors, I mean things of the form $\otimes_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \psi_i$ where all but finitely many $\psi_i$ equal $p_i$), so you can easily extract an ONB from that. (Namely, choose an ONB for each $H_i$ that contains $p_i$, then finite tensors of elements of these ONB form an ONB of the tensor product.)

For $2$, I’m not sure what exactly you are trying to ask. Just check it like how you would check any given infinite series converges or diverges.

For $3$, I haven’t seen any other good definitions, and the definition you gave or some equivalent form of it is basically the standard used in my field. But perhaps there are other definitions that I’m simply unaware of.
